# Bottom limit for function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have this function

$f(d,l,p)=5 (4 d + l) (p-1 ) (d + l)^{1/(p-1 )}-(\frac{4 d + l}{4})^{1/(p-1)}(20 d (p-1 ) + l ( 5 p-3))$

and I am quite positive that $f(d,l,p)\geq 0$ for $p>1,d\geq 0$ and $l\geq 0$  (used Mathematica to plot it for various cases).

I know that $f(0,l,p)\geq 0$, so I tried l'Hospital but it did not work. Do you see a way to proof my assumption.

Thank you very much for any ideas you have.

Comment: No way to show this analytically?

Answer (score 1):

Put $r=\frac 1{p-1}$. Then $r>0$ and 
$f(d,l,p)=A-B$, where $A=\frac{5}{r}(4 d + l) (d + l)^r$ and $B=(\frac{4 d + l}{4})^r(\frac{20d}{r} + l (\frac{5}{r}+2))$. If $B\ne 0$ then by [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Generalization)
$$\frac AB=\frac{ 20d + 5l}{20d + 5l+2lr}\left(1+\frac{3l}{4d+l}\right)^r\ge 
\frac{ 20d + 5l}{20d + 5l+2lr}\left(1+\frac{3lr}{4d+l}\right)= 
\frac{5(4d+l+3lr)}{20d + 5l+2lr}\ge 1,$$
so $ f(d,l,p)=A-B\ge 0$.